# Can I use {contact.checksum} in membership confirmation receipt

Tags: email, checksum

I am using CiviCRM with WordPress 5.3.2.

I've managed to use the {contact.checksum} feature to send folks a link to edit their profile, in a one-off or bulk email.

Now, I would like to include that capability in the membership confirmation receipt.  I tried including it in the "Receipt Message", but apparently html isn't allowed there.  Should I try to insert it into the relevant system Workflow message?

I would also like to include it in the "Thank you footer" of the contribution (so that users can immediately edit their own data, without waiting for the email. But the link just give error ("No user/contact ID was specified, so the Profile cannot be used in edit mode.")  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can include token in any message template. The system workflow message template doesn't show editor hence you will need to add content in html format. But the normal message template does show ckeditor, if you want to provide a link to a text you can click on button [image] on ck editor option bar and add url with contact check sum.

Regarding Thankyou footer, its not possible to add tokens as CiviCRM doesn't support it at the moment, however you can certainly achieve this by implementing preProcess() or buildform() hook via extension/plugin/module.

Comment: Alas, my attempts to add any of the tokens causes me to receive a "There has been a critical error on your website." error when I submit the Contribution form.  I can insert simple text, but if I insert